# Why is elasticsearch python parallel_bulk using so much memory?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, memory, indexing

I have a pretty simple indexing task that reads line-delimited json from a file, does simple manipulation of incoming data, and then indexes using elasticsearch `parallel_bulk`. I am using python3, ES 6.7 on the server (2 nodes, 16G each).

When I run the code below, I see pretty steadily-increasing memory usage until the machine starts swapping. The data are not huge (<500 characters per line), so I am surprised by the memory usage.

I have done a little tuning of queue size, thread count, and chunk size and there is quite a bit of sensitivity. I'd like to optimize indexing speed on the client (I have done the work on the server side to speed things up) while keeping memory to a reasonable amount.

Code:

```
def yield_records(idx='sra_bulk_test_biosample'):
    for fname in list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.json.gz'),os.listdir())):
        print(fname)
        with gzip.open(fname, 'r') as f:
            n = 0
            for line in f:
                n+=1
                if(n % 10000 == 0):
                    print(n)
                res = json.loads(line)
                yield {
                    "_op_type": "index",                   # this is the default
                    "_index": idx,
                    "_type": 'doc',                        # no more doc types after es_6
                    "_id": res['accession'], # extract _id from record
                    "_source": res                         # use entire record as "source"
                }

def main():
    for success, info in parallel_bulk(es, actions = yield_records(), chunk_size=1000, queue_size=4, thread_count=4, yield_ok = False):
        if(not success):
            print(info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hi! please read here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/297#issuecomment-153522358